# python : ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.teammate.teammate/files/app/ibm_db_dlls/ibm_db.dll" has bad ELF magic

Tags: python-3.x, db2

i am trying to use ibm-db in my python-android app. i am getting below error when app runs on android phone:-
**python : ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.teammate.teammate/files/app/ibm_db_dlls/ibm_db.dll" has bad ELF magic**

please help to find a solution for this.

Comment: could you please include some code snippet, what you are doing?

Comment: Regardless of the solution, python ibm_db needs a Db2 driver to operate. Does IBM make available the clidriver for android? (clidriver is not open source so you cannot compile it yourself for your cpu architecture).

Comment: hi, i clidriver is  also there, it comes with installation but still i am getting this error.

Comment: Hey Jay, i am using IBM DB2 as a database and using Ibm-db package to connect and get the data from the DB2, everything works fine, only i get this error while app runs in android.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like you have PE32 Windows executable of the ibm_db and not ELF, which I assume is the result of you building your app on Windows. Are you able to install the module on the phone directly first

```
pip install ibm_db
```

or

```
easy_install ibm_db
```

and see if that helps? (i.e. then test if you can import the module). A similar problem is discussed also in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ibm_db/6JsLy3hD0ZM).

Comment: Hello , Thanks for replying,

Comment: i have used pip and easy_install also to install it again , so everytime buildozer works, it creates a Apk, ,but when i run it in android, app crashes with above error,

Comment: after easy_install you can import "Ibm_db" from Python on the phone? If yes. then it is more of buildozer, i.e. it must override/overwrite ibm_db library dependencies with version where the build runs (x86 vs ARM).

Comment: pyc files are getting created for android but but while getting imported in phone i get this error. if i comment out the dll reading line from the code thn ibm_db starts getting the elf error, but everything is working fine in the ubuntu as well as windows. Even database connectivity works in windows and ubuntu, i am getting this error when i create a apk file and run that apk on android. and i selected ARM v7 to create an apk, all other things running fine in the apk just ibm_db has issues. even google cloud and aws is working in android.

Comment: to issue with ibm_db code is that is is *not* pure Python code. So the problem are not *.pyc files. ibm_db is a Python binding to Db2 client, which is closed-source and written in C/C++. This driver is downloaded automatically during installation, see https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb for details. From what I see now, I have no idea how it could possibly work on Android (ARM) because on FTP from which dirver is downloaded (https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/) there is no ARM64 binary...